# How to name/call functions in OpenLayers2?

Tags: openlayers-2

I don't know well enough OpenLayers syntax, so I need to ask here. I need to name every function in OpenLayers (for creating map - tiles, for drawing markers on the map etc.). So, I have this simple code:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
"http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'});
```

I would need to put that inside the function and name that function, something like this:

```
function createMap() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'});
               }

createMap();
```

But that code doesn't work. So, can you tell me if this is possible and why my code doesn't work?

Comment: Where are you calling th3 function from? Usually it is called on the onLoad event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always necessary to specify, what "doesn't work" - does it give any error message, etc.

In your `createMap()` code, you create local variable `wms` and you don't do anything with it. Probably you want to add it to map:

```
var map;

function createMap() {
    // map goes into global variable
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

    // wms is local variable, won't be available later
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {
            layers: 'basic'
    });

    // Add layer to map
    map.addLayers([wms]);
}
```